# ASP.NET MVC Pass a String to a Controller through an AJAX Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to pass a string as a parameter for a controller in the URL of an AJAX call in a separate view. I want it to have the same nullable functionality as when you pass (int? id) in the controller, but instead be a string. Here's my code:

Separate View:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Save/"+string
}).done(function (data) {
    $('body').append('<p>Query was successfully saved to the database.</p>');
});
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Save(string? data)
    {
        if(data == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        return View(data);
    }
```

and the view for `Save` has virtually nothing in it, I'm just trying to print the string that was passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `string` is a class, so it cannot be nullable, i.e. you don't need `?` after parameter type declaration:

```
public ActionResult Save(string data)
```

Now in order to access this method you need correct URL. You did not write the name of your controller, so I will assume it is `SomeController`. Additionally, I assume that you are using default MVC routes, i.e. no custom ones. If these assumptions are valid the URL that you need is:

```
url: "/some/save/?data=yourvalue"
```

Let's break it down:

- `some` stands for the name of your controller, without a word `Controller`, so `SomeController` becomes `some` in URL.
- `save` is the name of your method.
- `data` is the name of the parameter in the method. Default routes have parameter `id` as third segment of URL, but your parameter is called `data`, so you need to pass it as query string.
- `yourvalue` is the value that will be passed to the method.

UPDATE: Another issue that was mentioned in comments, is that statement

```
return View(data);
```

is looking for a view which is provided in parameter value. This is expected behavior, because overload of method `View` with single parameter of type `string` is trying to render the view, which is passed as parameter.

To fix the issue, you should use overload with 2 parameters and pass the name of the view as first parameter and model as second:

```
return View("Save", data);
```

Comment: String as a reference type definitely can't be null, but he can still use 'Save(string data=string.empty)' as a default parameter if that's what he needs

Comment: @JasonRoner What I meant by saying that string cannot be nullable, is that `Nullable<T>` has type `T` restricted to `struct`, which makes statement `string?` invalid, because `string` is `class`, not `struct`. For `string` you can simply pass `null`, which often requires special handling in the code.

Comment: This isn't working for me, it's still trying to find a view for whatever value I put in for `data`

Comment: @KyleThompson I updated the answer, see if it works now

Comment: Works just fine now. Thanks for all the help!